# Is it possible to create generic function for Kotlin primitive arrays

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a print function for my `DoubleArray` and `BooleanArray`

```
// Print DoubleArray
fun print(arr: DoubleArray) {
        print("[")
        for (i in arr.indices) {
            if (i == arr.size - 1) print("${arr[i]}") else print("${arr[i]}, ")
        }
        print("]")
    }

// Print BooleanArray
fun print(arr: BooleanArray) {
        print("[")
        for (i in arr.indices) {
            if (i == arr.size - 1) print("${arr[i]}") else print("${arr[i]}, ")
        }
        print("]")
    }
```

Code is exactly the same for both cases except for the type of that parameter `arr`. If we were using `Array<T>`, it would be easy to use generics and merge them.

Is there a way to merge these codes into one using generics or using a different method?

Comment: I think this is not possible and we have to provide separate implementation for each primitive array. Anyway, your `print()` function actually reimplements `contentToString()` which is available for each array.